# restore folder Archivio Test Q2 [ID 2925829] - INGCDaaS

Tags: testing

I would like to restore the folder saved in https://dev.azure.com/IngEurCDaaS01/IngOne/_testPlans/define?planId=2155221&suiteId=2155222 until last night.

The name of the folder is Archivio Test Q2 [ID 2925829]  present in the address https://dev.azure.com/IngEurCDaaS01/IngOne/_testPlans/define?planId=2155221&suiteId=2155222
I mistakenly deleted the folder this morning.

Is it possible restore it in the same folder?

Thanks a lot
Martina

resotre the same folder Archivio Test Q2 [ID 2925829] in the same path     https://dev.azure.com/IngEurCDaaS01/IngOne/_testPlans/define?planId=2155221&suiteId=2155222

thanks a lot

Comment: This question doesn't match the standards of StackOverflow. Please read [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question properly or delete it and post a new one. Welcome to StackOverflow btw :)